# How do I open another workbook with multiple sheets and find matches?

Tags: excel, vba

The goal is to use a reference Excel workbook as a database to find matching BoxID and then copy cells D to G in the same row. Finally pasting to another workbook that consists of a single worksheet.

I figured Xlookup would be easiest. In Excel it works but it doesn't in VBA.

Three main questions

- How do I open another workbook and then reference all sheets or a specific range through all sheets in a dynamically named workbook to my current activeworkbook?
  (e.g. sheets will be named freezer 23, freezer 43, fridge 190 in database.)
  The rows of the sheets is variable but the columns stay the same.
- Is there a way to do the above but if nothing is found to leave the cell blank?
- Is there a way I could simplify this code?

On the left is the database which is going to be the external reference/where the data is coming from and on the right is the output sheet. Where I will be using Xlookup to search for the matching value.  column "A" is where the search value will be and output to the next 4 cells.
[image]

```vb
Sub FreezerPulls()
    
    Dim lastrow, j As Long
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim a As Integer
    Dim list As Workbook
    Dim frzdatabase As 
    
    Dim BoxIDlist, info, BoxIDdatabase, database, databasepath As String
    
    databasepath = ("C:\Users\mikeo\Desktop\DataBaseStandard.xlsm")
    Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\mikeo\Desktop\DataBaseStandard.xlsm")
    
    database = "DataBaseStandard.xlsm"
    Set list = ThisWorkbook
    
    list.Activate
    
    Set BoxIDlist = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Row.Count).End(xlUp).Row  'emphasized textthis doesn't work
    Set BoxIDdatabase = Range("A2:A1500")
    Set info = Range("D2:G1500")
    
    a = Application.Worksheets.Count
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Your "database" screenshot is confusing - it has multiple tabs - one per freezer - but the sheet displayed has rows from multiple freezers...  Are box ID's unique, or can they exist on multiple sheets or in multiple rows on the same sheet?   Your database would be easier to search/manage if you put all of the data on a single sheet, with an added "Freezer" column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this, using `Match()`. See comments in code

```vb
Sub FreezerPulls()
    
    Const DB_PATH As String = "C:\Users\mikeo\Desktop\DataBaseStandard.xlsm"
    Dim wbData As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, rw As Range, id, m
    
    Set wbData = Workbooks.Open(DB_PATH, ReadOnly:=True) 'get a reference to the data workbook
    
    'loop each row in the lookup table
    For Each rw In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A17:F40").Rows
        id = rw.Cells(1).Value                                'Box ID to find
        If Len(id) > 0 Then                                   'any value to look up?
            For Each ws In wbData.Worksheets                  'loop all worksheets in data workbook
                m = Application.Match(id, ws.Columns("A"), 0) 'any match on this sheet ColA?
                If Not IsError(m) Then                        'no error = match was made on row m
                    rw.Cells(3).Value = ws.Name               'add freezer name
                    rw.Cells(4).Resize(1, 3).Value = _
                          ws.Cells(m, 5).Resize(1, 3).Value   'copy segment, rackID, position
                    Exit For                                  'done searching (assumes box id's are unique)
                End If
            Next ws
        End If
    Next rw
    
    wbData.Close False

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That is very helpful and I appreciate it. I have been trying to get this to work for days.

Comment: I didn't know that I could do that!